# Add double quote if there is white space between words in column

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a requirement to generate a file from a table. I am using sed for streaming the data. I want to use a text qualifier if there is any white space in the table column.

**Sample input**

```
Unites State | California | UNIX | ABC DE
```

**Expected output**

```
"Unites State" | California | UNIX | "ABC DE"
```

Comment: This question could use some detail about what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo 'Unites State | California | UNIX | ABC DE' | sed -E 's/([^ |]+ +[^|]+)( +\||$)/"\1"\2/g'
"Unites State" | California | UNIX | "ABC DE"
```

- Assumes there is always a space before `|`
- `-E` use ERE, some `sed` versions use `-r` instead
- `([^ |]+ +[^|]+)` non-space, non-`|` characters followed by at least one space and then non-`|` characters
- `( +\||$)` above pattern followed by at least one space and then `|` or end of line
- `"\1"\2` quote as per requirement

Answer (score 1):

Not bad with Perl:

```
echo $'Unites State | California | UNIX | ABC DE' |perl -pe 's/[a-zA-Z]+[[:space:]]+[a-zA-Z]+/\"$&\"/g'
"Unites State" | California | UNIX | "ABC DE"
```

Comment: That turns `Unites States of America | California | UNIX` into `"Unites States" "of America" | California | UNIX`

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly:

```
sed 's/[^ |][^|]* [^|]*[^| ]/"&"/g'
```

To account for other blank characters than ASCII space, use:

```
sed 's/[^[:blank:]|][^|]*[[:blank:]][^|]*[^|[:blank:]]/"&"/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TAB=`echo 'x' | tr 'x' '\011'`; # tab
SPC=`echo 'x' | tr 'x' '\040'`; # space
s="[$SPC$TAB]";                 # whitespace regex
W="[^|$TAB$SPC]";               # building block of a word
echo ' United  States   | California | UNIX|ABC DE' |
sed -e "s/\($W$W*$s$s*\)\{1,\}[^|][^|]*/\"&\"/g"
```

Comment: Instead of `TAB=$(echo 'x' | tr 'x' '\011'); # tab` you can just do `TAB=$'\t'` or `TAB=$'\011'`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou, `$'...'` is not standard. Standardly, nowadays, one could use `[[:blank:]]` or at least `TAB=$(printf '\t')`, but Rakesh's answer is portable even to systems from the 80s that didn't have `printf` or `$(...)`, let alone `$'...'`. Some very old `tr` implementations have also been known not to support `\t`, hence the `\011`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes that's correct. I've updated my answer to reflect the fix. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

due to I can not comment, answer here.

```
perl -pe 's/\w+\s+\w+/\"$&\"/g'
```

is more simple to George Vasiliou's answer.

Comment: Actually is the same answer using regex  abbreviations : \w for words a-zA-Z0-9 , \s for space

Comment: But has the same flaw, in that it 3 or 4 word fields are handled badly.

Answer (score 0):

In perl, I'd actually use `split`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#iterate data block below (use <> for reading STDIN)
while ( <DATA> ) {
   #split on whitespace|whitespace
   my @fields = split /\s*\|\s*/;
   #transform individual fields
   for ( @fields ) { 
      #check if it contains a space
      next unless m/\s/;
      #if it does, quote
      s/(^|$)/\"/g;
   }
   #print output; 
   print join " \| ", @fields,"\n";
} 

__DATA__
Unites State | California | UNIX | ABC DE
```

Which outputs:

```
"Unites State" | California | UNIX | "ABC DE"
```

But also copes with multi-word fields.

Simplifying this to a one liner, because all the cool kids are:

```
perl -F'\s*\|\s*' -lane '/\s/&&s/(^|$)/\"/g for @F;print join " \| ",@F'
```